# unable to run app from Google play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I create app named "onlineContact" that save your contact in cloud and you can access your contacts from any Android phone using login. This app is working fine when I test it. I connect my mobile with computer and run it from android studio it's good. So, I upload this app on Google Play Store but When I download and install app from play store it's not worked. What's the problem with this.

Here is my app link on Play store [onlineContact](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.azeem.onlinecontact)
Install it click on any link like login, create account or forget password.
When you clicked any of them it's crashed.

I tried it again from android studio and install it and it's working fine. Now how can I checked what the problem with this. I'm not able to place all code of my app here. Please help me about this what i can do.

**UPDATE**

Bulid.gradil(Modual:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.azeem.onlinecontact"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',        {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
}
```

**LoginActivity**

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}

protected void login(View view){
    EditText etxtPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxtPhoneNumber);
    EditText etxtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxtPassword);
    String phoneNumber = etxtPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
    String password = etxtPassword.getText().toString();
    String action = "login";

    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(action, phoneNumber, password);
}


protected void forgetPassActivity(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, ForgetPassword.class));
}

protected void createAccount(View view){
    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, CreateAccount.class);
    startActivity(loginIntent);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}

}
```

This activity open fine when I run app But it not work any further when I clicked on any button it will crashed.

Comment: Are you using ProGuard to obfuscate your code in production? Post your build.gradle please

Comment: Without code and a stack trace we can't do more than guess.

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler I update my question please check it. App is working fine when I installed it from android studio. But not working when I installed ot from play store

Comment: @GabeSechan It's a huge code. I'm not able to place all code here. I think if app is working from android studio it must must need to work on play store. But in my case it's not.

Comment: Place the relevant code based on the attack trace here

Comment: @GabeSechan Check update. When I install app login activity show it fine but when I click on any thing here it will crashed.

Comment: You could add [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics) to your app. and update it in the store. It's free, quite easy and you'll get crash reports whenever it crashes on someone.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen But I need the reason why it crashed. Currently app crashed in all devices.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen Problem is app not crashed when I run it from android studio

Comment: The reports will show why it crashes.

Comment: And you can [use alpha/beta release channels](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/beta-tests.html) with limited users for new apps until you know that they are stable instead of making it public for the whole world right away.